# IP address by Domain Name

Tags: python

I am trying to get IP address of a domain..
i am using following code

```
>> import socket
>> socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
```

its giving me following error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

what is wrong with my code...is there any other way to get ip address by domain name in python..???
please help...

Comment: What environment are you running this code on?

Comment: @Rajesh, you should accept abhiasawa's answer so this is marked as closed.

Comment: Agree with Wooble. you probably dont have a DNS configured. Can you paste the output of ping or nslookup to google.com.

Comment: Any chance any of you know how to do this with Javascript?

Answer (score 19):

Your code is correct.
Perhaps you have a firewall in between you and these servers that is blocking the request?

Comment: This is the most likely answer. Either that or @Rajesh is using a different computer to the one on which this question was asked and that machine does not have a network connection :-)

Comment: When you say `these servers`, which servers are you referring to?

Comment: The issue is not being able to get a DNS lookup response, not a failure to connect to www.google.com.

Answer (score 7):

```
import socket
domainName = input('Enter the domain name: ')
print(socket.gethostbyname(domainName))
```

I think you forgot to print it because it works for me.

Comment: Works fast, easy and also in windows, anaconda directly. If you need to use the ip, it would be 
`domainName = 'anydomain.here'
ip= socket.gethostbyname(domainName)

print ("IP:", ip)`

Answer (score 3):

```
# Python3 code to display hostname and 
# IP address 

# Importing socket library 
import socket 

# Function to display hostname and 
# IP address 
def get_Host_name_IP(): 
    try: 
        host_name = socket.gethostname() 
        host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name) 
        print("Hostname : ",host_name) 
        print("IP : ",host_ip) 
    except: 
        print("Unable to get Hostname and IP") 

# Driver code 
get_Host_name_IP() #Function call 

#This code is conributed by "Sharad_Bhardwaj".
```

Answer (score 0):

That error also appears when the domain is not hosted anywhere (is not connected to any IP, any nameserver) or simply does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

Here is full example, how you can get IP address by Domain Name.

```py
import urllib.parse
import socket
import dns.resolver

def get_ip(target):
    try:
        print(socket.gethostbyname(target))
    except socket.gaierror:
        res = head(target, allow_redirects=True)
        try:
            print(r.headers['Host'])
        except KeyError:
            parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(target)
            hostname = parsed_url.hostname
            try:
                answers = dns.resolver.query(hostname, 'A')
                for rdata in answers:
                    print(rdata.address)
            except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
                print('ip not found')

get_ip('example.com')
```